# Node js and heroku variable storing issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

I developed a quick game to play with my friends. The objective of the game is to see who presses the space bar the most times(we are very simple minded people). I made the app with node js and deployed it with heroku. The issue that I am having is that after a while of not being in use the variable for the top score resets. I don't really know how to fix this or even if there is a way to fix this but if you can help it would be much appreciated.
This is the url of the site if it helps
https://space-king.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 0):

I believe your app goes sleep after not receiving any traffic in 1 hour.
You can take a look at these links:

1. https://blog.heroku.com/app_sleeping_on_heroku
2. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/free-dyno-hours

Comment: Thanks for the help this gives me a good starting point for fixing the issue.